# Offline HTML report to access filesystem

Tags: javascript, html, report, node-webkit, hta

I am making a HTML report that has to be auto-generated out of a native code application.This HTml report can be a bunch of files with HTML components(js,css..), But this will be used as a report only and not with a webserver. In this report i need to add many data tables and graphs where im intending to use libs like d3. Here ,

1. 1.how do i add and remove data from a browser session without server so that i can load data from the folder to browser to display it as
   graph. and clear the data from Ram as soon as the page is navigated
   out of a chart view (This is a huge data). so adding and clearing
   the data will help to make the application responsive.
2. How do i save a file like "user.conf" file that saves , say, axis scaling factors that user of the report changes as they view the
   report. so while he repoens the report with the bunch of file, it
   can read the previous setting and display it in proper scaling.

I found only two solutions for this problem,

1. HTA app. - This technology seems to be deprecated and im not sure if it supports are new javascripts and interactive svg from D3. this seems to be a learning and implementation in a little different direction than actual HTML development, not able to judge if this is a worthy tryout.
2. To build a NWjs app - This is a straight forward solution. But when i tried this, A report (to be standalone) comes around minimum of 50mb. this makes no sense from the application perspective. To bundle a Webkit runtime to a html for every report makes no sense. A work around is to make this NWjs as a one time installation and to open *.nw file (ZIP file of all web contents) from the report using this tool. this is not elegant as i will request users to install this package and on top of it, the portability of html and not having to install any other software for viewing a html is lost.

Any/all answers for making a HTML report that can access the file system for saving the preferences without a web server concept will be highly useful.

Comment: I generate my HTML reports via a headless browser, (phantomjs), and then save them as PDF's.  HTML is not a great way to send reports to people.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know the browser is not allowed to get to the file-system for security reasons.
You said it is going to be an offline app so what you want is actually a desktop offline app.
You can create it using web technologies with http://electron.atom.io/

I hope it helps.

Comment: This is almost same as NW. except that it has different technology. but rest remains same to carry ~50 mb webkit/v8 load with the app